# Número máximo de conexões concorrentes excedida no Apache HTTP

Tags: apache

Estou usando o servidor HTTP Apache 1.3.29

Atualmente, estou com um servidor Apache que está apresentando o erro:

> Internal Server Error 500 Exception: EWebBrokerException Message: Maximum number of concurrent connections exceeded. Please try again later

Esta mensagem aparece quando muitos usuários estão usando o sistema, mas não sei o número de conexões para causar isso.

Eu preciso de ajuda para otimizar o servidor suportar mais conexões / acesso

Aqui estão as partes importantes do `httpd.conf` do servidor:

```
ServerType standalone

PidFile logs/httpd.pid

ScoreBoardFile logs/apache_runtime_status

Timeout 5

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 0

KeepAliveTimeout 1

MaxRequestsPerChild 0

ThreadsPerChild 500


ClearModuleList

AddModule mod_so.c
AddModule mod_setenvif.c

Port 80

DocumentRoot "C:/Arquivos de programas/Apache Group/Apache/htdocs"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Arquivos de programas/Apache Group/Apache/htdocs">


Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AllowOverride None

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir "C:/Arquivos de programas/Apache Group/Apache/users/"
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>


AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>

UseCanonicalName On


<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
</IfModule>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>


HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog logs/error.log

LogLevel warn

ServerSignature On


<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>

      IndexOptions FancyIndexing

        AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

    AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
    AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
    AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
    AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

    AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
    AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
    AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
    AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
    AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
    AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
    AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
    AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
    AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
    AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
    AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
    AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
    AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
    AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
    AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
    AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

    AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
    AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
    AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
    AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^

    DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif


    ReadmeName README
    HeaderName HEADER

        IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    AddType application/x-tar .tgz

    AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        LanguagePriority en da nl et fr de el it ja kr no pl pt pt-br ru ltz ca es sv tw
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Não é por falta de recursos da máquina. O servidor tem 16GB de RAM e um ótimo processador, quando o problema ocorre o consumo não está nem em 30%, talvez algum ajuste no Apache.

Comment: Perdoe-me o comentário, mas por que está usando uma versão **tão** antiga do apache?

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão o número máximo de conexões é 256, conforme a [documentação](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#maxclients).

Para aumentar, você pode tentar incluir (ou alterar) no seu `httpd.conf` algo como isto:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    MaxClients          1000
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadsPerChild      25
</IfModule>
```

[Aqui](http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_apache_web_server_for_maximum_concurrent_connections_or_increase_max_clients_in_apache) você poderá ver uma extensa descrição de como otimizar as configurações para conexões concorrentes e/ou número máximo de clientes.

Answer (score 0):

Qual sistema operacional você está usando?

Para visualizar as conexões ativas em seu servidor, digite esse comando no prompt:

```
netstat -an | grep :8025 | grep -i EST | wc -l
```

*onde 8025 é a porta do seu apache;

Pronto, agora você consegue ter uma ideia das conexões ativa em seu servidor.

Insira essa otimização para 1000 clientes no seu httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
  ServerLimit 40
  StartServers 2
  MaxClients 1000
  MinSpareThreads 25
  MaxSpareThreads 75 
ThreadsPerChild 25
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
</ IfModule>
```

[Aqui](http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_apache_web_server_for_maximum_concurrent_connections_or_increase_max_clients_in_apache) um link explicando esse erro.